# How to refactor this higher order function

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am having some trouble trying to refactor this "every" function so that it uses a built-in "reduce" method.

This is Javascript

```
const greaterThan5 = num => true ? num > 5 : false;

function every(array, callback) {
    for (let element of array) {
        if (callback(element) === false) return false
      }
    return true;
}

function every (array, callback) {
    return array.reduce(function (acc, cur){
     // IDK what to put here
    }, callback(array[0]) 
}

console.log('expected : false', every([10, -20, 30], greaterThan5))
console.log('expected : true', every([10, 20, 30], greaterThan5))
```

Comment: why would you use reduce? It is not equivalent. Equivalent is .every()

Comment: There are forEach, map, every, some, find, findIndex ... reduce is just one among those, and in this case *its the wrong tool for the job* What's wrong with `[10, -20, 30].every(greaterThan5)` ?

Comment: It was part of the interview for a bootcamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function every(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    if (acc) {
      return callback(cur);
    }
    return false;
  }, true);
}
```

The only difference is, the first solution will stop at the first `false` while the one with `reduce()` will go on until all the array elements are checked.

**Tests**

```js
function every(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    if (acc) {
      return callback(cur);
    }
    return false;
  }, true);
}

console.log(every([1,2,3,4], (n) => n < 5));
console.log(every([1,2,5,4], (n) => n < 5));
```

Within `reduce()` it doesn't stop after `false`:

```js
function every(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    console.log("Checking " + cur + "...");
    if (acc) {
      return callback(cur);
    }
    return false;
  }, true);
}

console.log(every([1,2,3,4], (n) => n < 5));
console.log(every([1,2,5,4], (n) => n < 5));
```

Comment: Thank you very much